# My PC won't ping my router

Tags: vlan

I'm trying to get my PC to ping the router.

[image]

The configuration on Fa0 of my router is

interface FastEthernet0

switchport access vlan 100

switchport mode trunk

and vlan 100 is

interface Vlan100

description LAN

mac-address 00d0.58b7.1c01

ip address 10.96.212.193 255.255.255.192

No configurations have been made on switchport Fa0/1 and Fa0/2.

[image]

I'm new to networking. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> No configurations have been made on switchport Fa0/1 and Fa0/2.

That is the problem. `switchport mode trunk` on the router tags all frames belonging to VLAN 100 (or any other). The switch's unconfigured Fa0/1 then drops those frames. In the reverse direction, frames from the PC run untagged to the router's Fa0,  and, lacking proper configuration, are dropped as well.

You'll need to

1. create VLAN 100 on the switch
2. configure Fa0/2 as access port for VLAN 100
3. configure Fa0/1 as trunk port